# Input Undefined (Octave)

Tags: octave

I have the following form of code written in a new script:

```
function f1=f1(X,Y)
  A=f2(X,Y)
end
```

where `f2` is written in another script. I assigned vectors for both X and Y, both working with `f2` just fine. But when I write it for the new script, the console displays

> 'X' undefined near line 3, column 3

Line 3 is the first time the input X appears in `f2(X,Y)`. The problem doesn't appear when I rewrite `f2` right into this script. The problem also doesn't appear for Y.

I can't seem to find the problem and I want to know where I went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `f2` look like?

Comment: Please include both f1 and f2, the command you're calling them with, and the output you get.  Are f1 and f2 both saved in the same location, and is that your current working directory?

Comment: And maybe there was more to the error message here? Often, Octave error messages include line numbers and maybe a stack trace.